# How to implement Alamofire RequestRetrier to deal with ResponseSerializationFailure?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire

I am trying to set up a class that follows the Alamofire RequestRetrier protocol to possibly deal with this error that I receive sometimes when doing a post request. This seems like it could be a way to retry the request until I get a non-zero length response. I am really struggling to understand the Alamofire documentation on this, and it uses the 0Auth2 library which I do not know if I need and understand even less.

My request line looks like this:

`Alamofire.request(request_url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON`

The request works most of the time and I receive my block of JSON, but sometimes I get this error:

`responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)`

I simply want to check for this error and retry the request until I receive a response.